# Seattle Athletes

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

Each of the clues below gives two words.  In each case, those two words share a certain relationship; that relationship in turn gives you a single letter.  The 17 resulting letters spell out two final words.  To verify that you have the right two words, they will have the same relationship that all of the individual answers had, and the single letter resulting from that relationship is `E`.

(Numbers in parentheses after each clue give the length of the *shorter* of the two answer words.  The reason why I'm not also giving you the length of the longer word will not become apparent until it's too late for that information to do you any good.)

1. Let's take the Czech capital to the next level! (6)
2. Getting rid of certain superheroes. (6)
3. A person born in Hanoi. (6)
4. The peril of perusing books. (6)
5. Of course I am capable of perusing books! (8)
6. Nice celestial objects to visit. (7)
7. Count the characters in your login. (7)
8. Antarctica didn't do it! (8)
9. I will not tell anyone where the middles are! (6)
10. Giants of the train depot. (6)
11. Someone who sells green gems. (6)
12. Or maybe blue gems? (7)
13. I'll tell you how many stars these movies received - for free! (6)
14. The flowing water just got here. (5)
15. Imitation electron. (7)
16. Warlike substance. (7)
17. An infinite number of magnifying glasses. (6)

(This is similar in style to my two previous postings here, but I think this one will be considerably more challenging.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The longer word is formed by adding one letter to the shorter word and rearranging letters. For example (as pointed out by [Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64624/seattle-athletes#comment195918_64626)), in the title, SEATTLE + H -> ATHLETES.

1. Let's take the Czech capital to the next level! (6)

   > UPGRADE PRAGUE -> D
2. Getting rid of certain superheroes. (6)

   > MARVEL REMOVAL -> O
3. A person born in Hanoi. (6)

   > VIETNAM NATIVE -> M
4. The peril of perusing books. (6)

   > READING DANGER -> I
5. Of course I am capable of perusing books! (8)

   > CERTAINLY LITERACY -> N
6. Nice celestial objects to visit. (7)

   > PLEASANT PLANETS -> A
7. Count the characters in your login. (7)

   > MEASURE USERNAME -> N
8. Antarctica didn't do it! (8)

   > INNOCENT CONTINENT -> T
9. I will not tell anyone where the middles are! (6)

   > SECRET CENTERS -> N
10. Giants of the train depot. (6)

    > STATION TITANS -> O
11. Someone who sells green gems. (6)

    > EMERALD DEALER -> M
12. Or maybe blue gems? (7)

    > SAPPHIRE PERHAPS -> I
13. I'll tell you how many stars these movies received - for free! (6)

    > GRATIS RATINGS -> N
14. The flowing water just got here. (5)

    > RIVER ARRIVE -> A
15. Imitation electron. (7)

    > PARTICLE REPLICA -> T
16. Warlike substance. (7)

    > MARTIAL MATERIAL -> E
17. An infinite number of magnifying glasses. (6)

    > ENDLESS LENSES -> D

> The added letters give DOMINANT NOMINATED -> E.

Comment: Was halfway done. Nice work.

Comment: (also note that the title follows the same pattern)

Comment: Also halfway done. Really fast work there.

Comment: All exactly correct!